# Couldn't change the icon on some phone while testing android application. What could be the reasons?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have developed an android application. After completion of application, I have changed the icon of app. But when I install it again on phones, icon is not getting changed on some phones. While it changed on some phones.

I have tested it on Xioami MI3 (Icon is not changing)
Moto g (Icon is changing)
Samsung Galaxy S5 (Icon is not changing)

I have tried this possibilities.
1. Clean and Build the project on Eclipse.
2. Tried other Icon.
3. Renamed Application.

Please Help, What should I do ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you changed icons for all ressources (hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved.
There is problem with MIUI.
It caches all the icons.
I have changed the theme and now it works.